# Product Alerts in Customer accounts?

Tags: magento-1.9, alert

I would like to know if someone finds a way to get these:

- Product Alerts in the Customer account, with Delete options (so that
  customers can proactively manage their subscriptions).
- Products Alert in the Customer account (the one an administrator can access in backend).

This is very useful if you use Product Alerts in your store. A customer can see what are the subscriptions.

As administrator visiting customer accounts you can see Product Alerts section like in product editing and there are the subscriptions of that customer.

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento CE 1.9.2.4

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? Seems like a shortcoming of Magento i.e not allowing customers to proactively manage their alert subscriptions.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not solution yet. Seeing Wish List, Product Alert in Customer accounts it is a must have, because you can manage promotion and you are not blind to your visitors information. Magento missed this important feature giving Wish Lists and Price Alerts a special section in Backend.